# Using href="#" to individually display multiple divs on a single webpage

Tags: html, css

I've been looking for an answer to my question and I can't figure out the proper wording and whatnot. Basically, I'm trying to replicate something that [this webpage](https://html5up.net/dimension) does when it transitions from one "page" to another.

Comment: The page @ Dimension, which you reference, uses JS Query.  I suggest W3C Slidy, which is probably simpler to implement.  e.g., [Web of Applications](https://www.w3.org/2006/02/woa/). [Slidy slide #6](https://www.w3.org/Talks/Tools/Slidy2/#(6))

Comment: Sounds like you want a [single-page application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application). You’d usually use a framework for that. A router component will take care of determining what to show.

Answer (score 2):

When you creating some HTML element, let say for example `<div>...content...</div>` you can assign  a name to it as `<div name="MySection1">..content...</div>` then you can reference to this element as `<a href="#MySection1">My section is here</a>` inside current page

You may want to  read this [document](https://www.w3.org/MarkUp/1995-archive/Elements/A.html) and this [one](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can try my example in JSFiddle. Simple popup boxes

https://jsfiddle.net/gordon_labour/ayaujuw3/21/

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser!  While we definitely appreciate examples, we usually recommend an attempt to answer the question alongside the example if possible.  Otherwise, this would be better as comment.  (I know you do not have the privilege earned yet, but unfortunately those are the rules.)